# Crontab out of memory

Tags: php, linux, apache, memory, cron

I'm running several crontabs now. I noticed that there are several crontabs take so much memory and some of them are using more than 512m so the system just throws an error.

Do you guys have any suggestions about how to save memory for crontab?

Thank you!

Comment: The crontab is running out of memory or a script you are calling via a cronjob?

Comment: can you provide the source of one that is running out of memory

Comment: @Anigel The crontab is running out of memory

Comment: @ChristopherMorrissey One example would be I use Zend to create search index? Or sometimes I send emails to all the users...

Comment: Then you indexing application or your code for sending mail is consuming a lot of memory and not cron.
The cron daemon only starts your script/application waits until the job is finished and handels STDOUT/STDERR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the script which your running needs more memory..

1. Try to reduce ARRAY usage from your CronTab Script.
2. Use Object return instead of Array return Values.
3. Search result from the Database should have Limit because of the memory issue.
4. Increase the PHP Memory.

If you can able to share the code of the logic It would be much helpful for us to provide you a suitable solution.